# Hidden anchor of functions in the treeview of doxygen

Tags: doxygen

I use doxygen to generate documentation for my C# codes and enabled the treeview. However, the treeview in the left included the anchor of functions. How could I disable them? Thanks for any suggestion.

See an example below

[image]

Comment: Been dealing with same question, found this thread:
http://doxygen.10944.n7.nabble.com/tree-view-td276.html
I posted a replay to Demitri, wasn't accepted yet. Did you found anything?

Comment: @krizajB I have solved this problem. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this question by myself. Firstly I created a DoxygenLayout.xml and specified LAYOUT_FILE            = DoxygenLayout.xml in the Doxyfile.

In the DoxygenLayout.xml, you need an empty child for memberdef. This is my own DoxygenLayout.xml:

```
<doxygenlayout version="1.0">
 <navindex>
    <tab type="mainpage" visible="yes" title=""/>
    <tab type="pages" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    <tab type="modules" visible="yes" title="Groups" intro=" "/>
    <tab type="namespaces" visible="yes" title="">
      <tab type="namespacelist" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="namespacemembers" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="classes" visible="yes" title="Functions">
      <tab type="classlist" visible="yes" title="Function list" intro=""/>
      <tab type="classindex" visible="$ALPHABETICAL_INDEX" title="Function index"/> 
      <tab type="hierarchy" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="classmembers" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <tab type="files" visible="yes" title="">
      <tab type="filelist" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
      <tab type="globals" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>
    </tab>
    <!-- <tab type="dirs" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>  -->
    <tab type="examples" visible="yes" title="" intro=""/>  
  </navindex>

  <!-- Layout definition for a class page -->
  <class>
    <briefdescription visible="yes"/>
    <includes visible="$SHOW_INCLUDE_FILES"/>
    <inheritancegraph visible="$CLASS_GRAPH"/>
    <collaborationgraph visible="$COLLABORATION_GRAPH"/>
    <allmemberslink visible="yes"/>
    <memberdecl>
    <!--
      <nestedclasses visible="yes" title=""/>
      <publictypes title=""/>
      <publicslots title=""/>
      <signals title=""/>
      <publicmethods title=""/>
      <publicstaticmethods title=""/>
      <publicattributes title=""/>
      <publicstaticattributes title=""/>
      <protectedtypes title=""/>
      <protectedslots title=""/>
      <protectedmethods title=""/>
      <protectedstaticmethods title=""/>
      <protectedattributes title=""/>
      <protectedstaticattributes title=""/>
      <packagetypes title=""/>
      <packagemethods title=""/>
      <packagestaticmethods title=""/>
      <packageattributes title=""/>
      <packagestaticattributes title=""/>
      <properties title=""/>
      <events title=""/>
      <privatetypes title=""/>
      <privateslots title=""/>
      <privatemethods title=""/>
      <privatestaticmethods title=""/>
      <privateattributes title=""/>
      <privatestaticattributes title=""/>
      <friends title=""/>
      <related title="" subtitle=""/>
      <membergroups visible="yes"/>
    -->
    </memberdecl>
    <detaileddescription title=""/>
    <memberdef>
    <!--
      <inlineclasses title=""/>
      <typedefs title=""/>
      <enums title=""/>
      <constructors title=""/>
      <functions title=""/>
      <related title=""/>
      <variables title=""/>
      <properties title=""/>
      <events title=""/>
    -->
    </memberdef>
    <usedfiles visible="$SHOW_USED_FILES"/>
    <authorsection visible="yes"/>
  </class>

</doxygenlayout>
```

Comment: Hmm, from looks of it, this also hides the function descriptions on the class page. Or am I missing something? Oh well, was getting excited about it way to fast rofl

Comment: An empty memberdecl children will hide functions, methods, etc. You could enable it if you like.

Comment: Well yes, but that brings me back on the start :) How is this solution even useful for you? Doesn't everyone need a function description documentation?

Comment: I am writing an API documentation and just want to show the inputs and outputs of each class, ignoring the member variables, functions, etc.